# Why is my ceiling fan not responding to the remote?

Tags: remote-control

This has happened a couple times over the years and we’ve been able to reset it but our attempts aren’t working this time. The ceiling fan remote (dd4t4-9v) has a fresh 9v battery but the fan doesn’t respond to it at all.

What are we missing?

[image]

Comment: did you try holding it very close

Comment: did you try changing the channel

Comment: if it's just some of the buttons, take it apart and clean the membrane button contacts on the circuit board. Isopropyl works well. If it's heavily tarnished, a pencil eraser can help, but don't rub so hard that your wear down the circuit trace. Once re-assembled the buttons should work much better.

Comment: Make and model of fan will help us find an answer.  A guess is that some of these require you to remove power to the fan receiver by turning off a wall switch, if one is available, or turning off the breaker for about 10 seconds. then allowing the remote to "search" for the signal to sync up with the receiver.

Comment: ...that it's not uncommon for electronic devices to actually fail after a number of years? Depending what's happening try things mentioned above, but they are made to (mostly) live past the warranty period, not forever. Eventually replacement is needed, because some component died, or something corroded, and they are not generally built so that repair is fiscally sensible .vs. replacement.

Comment: Try a known good battery, not all new ones are ok.

Answer (score 5):

Figured this out after determining the brand of ceiling fan. The fan in question is a Patriot Lighting Atilla model, sold through Menards. I started to just replace the remote and receiver but kept running in to roadblocks because the fans reverse function is controlled solely from the remote, there is no physical switch on the fan housing. Once I knew the model I was able to track down the installation instructions and low & behold they mentioned the reset procedure for the remote. If you have a Patriot Lighting ceiling fan / fixture and the remote doesn’t seem to be responding then try these steps:

1. Turn off power to the fan via the switch on the wall
2. Turn on power via the switch on the wall
3. Within 10 seconds press and hold the ‘Fan Off’ button on the remote for 3 seconds
4. The light on the fan will begin to flash, this indicates that the reset was successful
5. Use the remote to turn on/off the fan and light to verify functionality

Note that on step 3 I had found similar instructions online for the particular remote model number but the online instructions said to “wait for 10 seconds then press and hold the fan off button”, this is incorrect and you should instead follow step 3.